# Как по нажатию первой кнопки начать выполнять функцию второй?

Tags: javascript, html

Существует такая форма

```
<form name="cartform" method=post>
     ....поля для ввода...
 </form>
```

Есть две кнопки:

```
<input type="submit" name="update"> //первая кнопка
<input  src="refresh.png" onclick="cl1();" type="image">  //вторая кнопка
```

И есть скрипт, который по сути должен отправлять форму с именем cartform по нажатию на вторую кнопку

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cl1 () {
        document.forms['cartform'].submit.click()
    }
</script>
```

Но что-то ничего не отправляется. Если кликать по первой кнопке, то всё окей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
document.forms['cartform'].submit.click()
```

на

```
document.forms['cartform'].submit();
```